# Python OS and subprocess for grep

Tags: python, unix, operating-system, subprocess, os.system

I'm trying to execute: grep -A5000 -m1 -e 'dog 123 4335' animals.txt in python script.

**Input file:**

```
cat 13123 23424 
deer 2131 213132
bear 2313 21313
dog 123 4335
cat 13123 23424 
deer 2131 213132
bear 2313 21313
```

**Output:**

```
cat 13123 23424 
deer 2131 213132
bear 2313 21313
```

I tried this command in Unix it works fine. But it's not getting executed using python the OS.system or the subprocess. Please give me the solution for either one.

Comment: Please share your python code so that we can debug furthur why it didn't work in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `subprocess`:

```
import subprocess

CMD = "grep -A5000 -m1 -e 'dog 123 4335' animals.txt"
p = subprocess.run(CMD, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(p.stdout.decode())
```

Output:

```
dog 123 4335
cat 13123 23424 
deer 2131 213132
bear 2313 21313
```